# Sympy solve will not finish running to a symbol equation

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I am trying to find the equilibrium points for a set of three differential equations, but the code is hanging and not finish running, I do not know if the equations are done incorrectly or if there is some type of mistake in how they were written.

```
#Variables
C = sym.Symbol('C')
A = sym.Symbol('A')
P = sym.Symbol('P')
r_c = sym.Symbol('r_c')
r_a = sym.Symbol('r_a')
K_c = sym.Symbol('K_c')
K_a = sym.Symbol('K_a')
beta_ca = sym.Symbol('beta_ca')
delta = sym.Symbol('delta')
gamma = sym.Symbol('gamma')
e = sym.Symbol('e')
alpha = sym.Symbol('alpha')
theta = sym.Symbol('theta')
p = sym.Symbol('p')



# Equations
dCdt = (r_c*C)*(1-(C/K_c)-((beta_ca*A)/K_c))-(delta*C)+(gamma*e)

dAdt = (r_a*A)*(1-(A/K_a)-((beta_ca*C)/K_a))-(A*alpha*P)

dPdt = (theta*A*P)-(p*P)

#Solving
solution = sym.solve((dCdt, dAdt, dPdt), (C, A, P))
```

Comment: Is the code "not running at all" or does it seem to hang, as the title says?

Comment: The solver is just taking awhile to find and succinctly represent all solutions. If you don't care about some potential overlap/duplication you can take the output from just two of the equations, e.g. `L = solve((dAdt,dCdt), (C,A,P))`, and merge that with the third, e.g. `[sol for L in [solve((dPdt, *(k-v for k,v in d.items())), (C,A,P)) for d in L] for sol in L]`. It'll run in a fraction of the time but not be quite as nice as what you might get from just solving the whole system.

Comment: Thanks it finishes runnning now, but runs into trouble with the tuple not having an items attribute I am not to well versed in how you were merging the solutions